# How to do casting map?

Tags: c++

```
 template <class S>
 struct C {
     S* operator()(void* c) { return (S*)c; }
 };
```

Idea is that I can do:

```
C<QRadioButton> caster;
void* p = ??;
caster(p)->width();
```

where p is a pointer to a QRadioButton, but kept as a void*.

What I'd like to do is keep a map of caster objects, e.g.

```
map<std::string, ??> Caster;

Caster["radio"]    = C<QRadioButton>;
Caster["checkbox"] = C<QCheckBox>;
```

So that I could do:

```
Caster["radio"](p)->width();
```

Any idea how to set this up?

Comment: Please use your words to form a coherent question.

Comment: Can you clarify your question ? What is `c` in your `struct C` ?

Comment: @iammilind ``c`` is the pointer given to the function ``operator()``.

Comment: @Darhuuk, sorry I missed it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure, but it looks like you want to use [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/any.html)

Comment: that still requires casting (or test casting). What I was trying to avoid was something like:

 if (type=="radio") (QRadioButton*)p->width();